# How to insert and view images from oracle using jsf

Tags: jsf-2

Can anyone please give me some code example or link of article explaining that how can i insert and view images to/from oracle using jsf?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these two tutorials:

[Uploading files with jsf 2](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html)

[Serving images with a servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-142.html) has nothing to do with jsf bust it shows how to insert files and read them from/to oracle, hope it helps.